# Tableau extension of data

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

I have a bit of a challenging question.

I have a dataset, A, that goes from 2012 till 2016 on a weekly basis, some columns contain data all the way down to 2016, whereas other stops at Week 35 in 2015 where it is then made up by NULL values.

I have another dataset, B, that goes from Week 36 2015 till 2016, This dataset is linked to dataset A by date. and this dataset, B, is a CSV file

Dataset B contains the columns that are missing data. These values can be changed therefore it is seperated from the dataset A.

I have made this formula in order to extend a data column from dataset A by the values of dataset B:

```
iif(ISNULL(IIF(ISNULL(SUM([Display]) ), SUM([Medieplan].[Display])*[Parameters].[Display]/100, SUM([Display]) )),0,
IIF(ISNULL(SUM([Display]) ), SUM([Medieplan].[Display])*[Parameters].[Display]/100, SUM([Display]) ))
```

Here "Display" is the column that is in need of extension, dataset B is called "Medieplan", and the parameter is a value that acts like a percantage that can be adjusted.

My problem is that when looking at a table of the data, it is not showing the values that I am requesting.
When looking at the Display Column, and the Display extended Column side by side for each week, we can see an extention in the values.
But looking at the Display Column and Display Extended Column on a yearly basis does not reveal any new data from the extended column.

I need help to remake the formula in order to have this made possible.

Another way to solve my issue, is by creating a parameter for each column with missing data

Here I have tried creating this formula

```
IF(ISNULL(SUM([Display])), [Extended - Display 36]*[Parameters].[Display]/100, SUM([Display]))
```

where "Extended - Display 36" represents the value at week 36 for 2015.

My problem here is that I dont know how to create a formula that takes into account the fact that there should be multiple values (one for each week), and not just one (week 36)

Hope this makes sense,

I appreaciate any help :-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is difficult to create a prototype of your problem . Could you please share any public link which we can download and work upon .

Comment: That is a good idea, I have uploaded a simplified model at wetransfer, here is the link:
http://we.tl/h7rQFd1gEZ

The sheet Year, indicates the data in a yearly basis, while Week indicates the data in Weekly basis... 

Display Extended (Original) shows the results correct in weekly basis, but not in yearly basis. "Display Extended" only shows the parameter, and I dont know how to correctly change multiple parameters. 

Thanks in advance

@minatverma